# How to convert near to yocto using assemblyscript?

Tags: nearprotocol, assemblyscript

If I have an amount less than 1 NEAR let's say .5 near, how do I convert it and store it using assemblyscript in a near protocol smart contract?

I tried to convert it to f64 first and make the arithmetic operation then convert it back to u128 like:

```
u128.fromF64((ONE_NEAR.toF64() * .5))
```

but fromF64 gives the following error

```
ExecutionError: 'WebAssembly trap: An arithmetic exception, e.g. divided by zero.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, you have to multiply the near amount (e.g. 1.25) by a large number first (e.g. 1000000) in order to preserve the fraction before you convert the number to Yocto using `toYoctob128(u128.from(amount))`.
and after the successful conversion, you can use `u128.div()` (e.g. `u128.div(amountInU128, u128.from(1000000))`) to get the correct value.

P.S.
The larger the number you multiply by first the more accurate the conversion will be but be careful not to exceed the `number` and `u128` limit.

Here is a complete example:

`Contract Class:`

```
  nearToYocto(x: string): u128 {
    let amountBase = (parseFloat(x) * BASE_TO_CONVERT);
    return u128.div(toYoctob128(u128.from(amountBase)), u128.from(BASE_TO_CONVERT));
  }
```

`utils:`

```
export const BASE_TO_CONVERT = 1000000.0;

export function toYoctob128(amount: u128): u128 {
  return u128.mul(ONE_NEAR, amount)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. You need to operate on yoctoNEAR instead of 0.5 NEAR.

Below examples are taken directly from the docs

https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-quick-reference#utils

**NEAR => yoctoNEAR**

```ts
// converts NEAR amount into yoctoNEAR (10^-24)

const { utils } = nearAPI;
const amountInYocto = utils.format.parseNearAmount("1");
```

**YoctoNEAR => NEAR**

```ts
// converts yoctoNEAR (10^-24) amount into NEAR

const { utils } = nearAPI;
const amountInNEAR = utils.format.formatNearAmount("1000000000000000000000000");
```

Comment: This is using JS sdk in the frontend of the dapp
I need something that can convert from near to yocto in my smart contact using assembly script 
for example
`let yocto = toYocto(.5)`
//yocto should have 5*10^23